# Fetching data with fetch api is not async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch-api

i have multiple devices which i want to fire a command over a api
But using fetch is not working as expected.
As you can see in the picture, 9 requests takes about a minute to finish, because the execution takes about 6 seconds per request. If i fire the command, they all appear in the dev console, but "pending" Why this is not working?

[image]

[image]

```
async function getExecuteOutput(devices, formData) {

    $.each(devices, async function( index, value ) {
        fetch(
            '/api/execute.php',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                body: foormData
            }
        ).then((resp) => resp.json()).then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Seems like your php code can't handle parallel responses for some reason.u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screenshot shows they are running in parallel. You can see the green bars in the screenshot starting at the same point. (Up to a point anyway: browsers limit the number of HTTP requests they can have in flight to the same server).

Your server-side code's inability to handle that (probably due to database locking) has nothing to do with `fetch`.

Comment: FYI: Its the maybe session locking in php, for everyone who have the same problem :)